# What is the meaning of "A is not as old as B"?

Tags: meaning, comparisons

In my understanding, the following sentence

> *A is not as old as B*.

may have 2 meanings, either

> *A is older than B*

or

> *A is newer than B*
>   .

So what is the actual meaning of  "A is not as old as B"?

Comment: Is this a language question or a logic one?  It seems to be a logic one, unless you are simply confused about the meaning of "not as old".  Also, your title does not match your question; they are asking different things.

Comment: I voted to close as general reference because this is a very basic grammatical question.  You might want to support the [English Languages Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) proposal, which would be a better home for such questions as these.

Comment: @itsbruce: For me "A is not as old as B" means either "A is older than B" or "A is newer than B".

Comment: @Lynn I see it more as "Not a real question"; too ambiguous and confused.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: I'm intrigued. How can you manage to understand *"A is not as old as B"* as meaning *"A is older than B"*? Would you therefore say *"A is not as big as B"* means the same as *"A is bigger than B"*? Surely you can see that *not as old as* means ***not** older than*, so how can it also mean *older than*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes. In my understanding "A is not as big as B" means that either "A is bigger than B" or "A is smaller than B". "Not older than" means either "as old as" or "newer than".

Comment: Are you saying that because if *"A is not **equal to** B"*, it follows that *"B is not **equal to** A"*? Bear in mind that only works with "equality" comparisons - if *"A is not **less than** B"*, the corollary is *"B is **greater than or equal to** B"*.

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether "A is not as old as B" means "A is not precisely as old as B" or "A is less old than B"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: "A is not as old as B" may mean either "A is older than B" or "A is newer than B".

Comment: I don't think you're realizing that native speakers would never consider your first reading

Comment: If you wrote something like: "Jack is not *as old* as Martin. In fact, Jack is much *older*." It would seem like a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A is not as old as B" means:

> B is older than A (and A is younger than B) (if A and B are living things)

Or

> A is *newer* than B (and B is older than A) (if A and B are objects)

Comment: And the answer to your question in the title is *no*.